# mark multiple dates dynamically react native wix

Tags: react-native

I'm using react-native-calendars. This library provides ability to mark dates on the calendar once mark parameter is passed to calendar object. I tried passing an array of objects but didn't worked sending multiple dates as below didn't worked as well.

How to dynamically mark multiple dates on it?

```
var nextDay =['2018-06-01',
       '2018-06-05',
       '2018-06-08',  
       '2018-06-07',
       '2018-06-18',
       '2018-06-17',
       '2018-05-28',
       '2018-05-29'];

   const mark = {
    [nextDay]: {selected: true, marked: true}
   };

this.state(
{
mark: mark,
})

          <Calendar
      onDayPress={this.onDayPress}      
      current={new Date()}
      minDate={'2018-05-24'}
      onMonthChange={(month) => {console.log('month changed', month)}}
      hideArrows={false}
      hideExtraDays={true}
      disableMonthChange={false}
      firstDay={1}
      hideDayNames={false}
      showWeekNumbers={false}
      onPressArrowLeft={substractMonth => substractMonth()}
      onPressArrowRight={addMonth => addMonth()}
      markedDates={this.state.mark}

          theme={{
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            calendarBackground: '#ffffff',
            textSectionTitleColor: '#b6c1cd',
            selectedDayBackgroundColor: '#00adf5',
            selectedDayTextColor: '#ffffff',
            todayTextColor: '#00adf5',
            dayTextColor: '#2d4150',
            textDisabledColor: '#d9e1e8',
            dotColor: '#00adf5',
            selectedDotColor: '#ffffff',
            arrowColor: 'orange',
            monthTextColor: 'blue',
            textMonthFontWeight: 'bold',
            textDayFontSize: 16,
            textMonthFontSize: 16,
            textDayHeaderFontSize: 16
          }}
    />
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: the answer below worked for me.

Comment: @devedv it would be great if you accept the answer, so it will help others too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is one hack to create an object you wanted to create from the date array,**

Option is using `reduce` to convert the array into an object and just follow the code i have implemented using pure javascript

---

**Call function after you successfully get value in nextDay array**

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marked: null,
    };
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.anotherFunc();
}

// call function after you successfully get value in nextDay array

anotherFunc = () => {
    var obj = nextDay.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: {selected: true,marked: true}}), {});
    this.setState({ marked : obj});
}
```

**Now add this state to your calendar element**

```
<Calendar
    ...
    markedDates={this.state.marked}
    ...
/>
```

See the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597386/how-to-create-an-object-from-one-dimensional-array-and-static-string#50597421) I have asked for the same on SO

Comment: Hey! How to use the customStyle option with the above solution?

Comment: You can add in the `obj` var in `{selected: true, marked: true, customStyles: {text:{ color: "red" }}}` something like this.

Comment: It's work for me.. Thanks a lot.. can you tell me what is the meaning of empty cult braces in another function. `anotherFunc = () => {
    var obj = nextDay.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: {selected: true,marked: true}}),`  **{}** `);
    this.setState({ marked : obj});
}`

Comment: @Chanaka the empty {} in the of reduce is the initial value. This means that the initial value is an empty object

Comment: Here it should be changed is not it?  `this.state = {
        marked: null,
    };`  otherwise i get a warn **Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `markedDates` of type `boolean` supplied to `CalendarList`, expected `object`.**

Comment: @Chanaka I have created example of this before 6 months so I have not that code, let me know if this removes warning, I will update it.

Comment: @KirankumarDafda cahnge `this.state = { marked: null, };` then warn is gone.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it and it worked :

```js
const nextDate = [
  '2021-06-28',
  '2021-06-29',
  '2021-07-04',
  '2021-07-5',
  '2021-09-06',
  '2021-08-05',
];

let mark = {};

nextDate.forEach(day => {
  mark[day] = {
    marked: true,
  };
});
```

Then Put the mark Object inside the `markedDates` in the Calendar

```js
markedDates={mark}
```

Make sure the dates are in object structure

Answer (score 0):

```
const [markedDates, setMarkedDates] = useState({});
    const type = { key: "1", color: red };
            
    const keys = Object.keys(arr);
                         keys.map((key) => {
                            const itemValue = arr[key]
                       
                                mark[key] = {
                                    dots: [type]
                                }
            
                                return null
                            
                        })
setMarkedDates(mark)
        
        then you can pass to markedDates={markedDates}
```