# How to create an object from one dimensional array and static string

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want an object like

```
var obj = {
    "ABC" : { name: true, dob: true},
    "CDE" : { name: true, dob: true},
    "EFG" : { name: true, dob: true},
    "CBA" : { name: true, dob: true},
    "XYZ" : { name: true, dob: true},
}
```

## currently I have only array of

```
var arr = ["ABC","CDE","EFG","CBA","XYZ"];
```

---

I have tried adding this with

```
newArray.push({
    key: arr[i],
    name: true,
    dob: true
});

var newObj = {}

newObj[i] = newArray;
```

but I am not able to pass this as an whole object to my code. when I stringify this it returns

## output

```
{
    '0':"[{
        key: "ABC",
        name: true,
        dob: true
    },{
        key: "CDE",
        name: true,
        dob: true
    }]"
}
```

Comment: Your desired `obj` is invalid - there is no key for the inner object.

Comment: but i want it as an key itself. Is this possible ?

Comment: An object is a collection of key-value pairs. You need a key and a value. If you want a non-string as a key, you'll need to use a Map instead.

Comment: Why do you use double curly braces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign` to create an object. Use spread operator and `map` to reiterate the array.

```js
var arr = ["ABC", "CDE", "EFG", "CBA", "XYZ"];

var obj = Object.assign(...arr.map(o => ({[o]: {name: true,dob: true}})));
console.log(obj);
```

Another option is using `reduce` to convert the array into a valid object.

```js
var arr = ["ABC", "CDE", "EFG", "CBA", "XYZ"];
var obj = arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v]: {name: true,dob: true}}), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: You are genius. Thank you so much. This worked for me :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me if what's that empty curl mean in your reduce function ?

Comment: @KirankumarDafda the empty `{}` in the of reduce is the initial value. This means that the initial value is an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var arr = ["ABC","CDE","EFG","CBA","XYZ"];

var result = arr.reduce((a,c) => {
a[c] = {name: true, dob: true};
return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick help, but i have tried @Eddie solution and it worked for me, I'll still try your solution. and update you :)

Comment: Reduce is working for me from both of you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["ABC","CDE","EFG","CBA","XYZ"];

let obj = {};

arr.forEach(x=> {
  obj[x] = {
    name: true,
    dob: true
  }  
});

console.log(obj)
```

Loop thru the array, for each of the element, use it as key and add an object as the value

Answer (score 0):

## This is another way in generating that output Object using JSON.parse()

```js
var objStr = '{'
var arr = ["ABC", "CDE", "EFG", "CBA", "XYZ"], 
    propertyValue = ':{"name":true,"dob":true}'

  for (var x in arr) {
   if (x < arr.length - 1)
    objStr += '"' + arr[x] + '"' + propertyValue + ','
   else
    objStr += '"' + arr[x] + '"' + propertyValue
  }
  objStr += '}'

  
console.log(JSON.parse(objStr))
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: As i was trying this for react native `JSON.parse` is not working for me.

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"

Comment: there object string that you are parsing might not be properly formatted,