# How do I concat two objects into one - React-Native state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Here are two objects one is creating onload of page while another is I want to add on button click into the current state

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        marked: null,
        tempMarkedDates: [],
    }
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}


// First object into marked is like

console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.marked));

Output ::

[
    {
        "2019-01-02":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-04":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-08":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-12-29":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-11-27":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#fc3232"
        },
    }
]
```

Working from my own answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50597708/3840093) on stack overflow

```
//Now I am creating new object like

day = "2019-01-10"
let obj = {};
obj[day] = {
    disabled: true, 
    selected: true, 
    selectedColor: '#fc3232'
}

//So the output will be

[
    {
        "2018-12-30":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to merge both the object and update **this.state.marked**

And it should be remain object after concatenation, while my code is changing it into array

```
Desire Output - Need to join last or first date object of 30-12-2018
[
    {
        "2019-01-02":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-04":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-08":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-12-29":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-11-27":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#fc3232"
        },
        "2018-12-30":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        }
    }
]
```

So need your help to concat the both object for React native state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the assign() method of javascript.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51143342/3449578

```
let newstate = Object.assign(obj , this.state.marked[0])

this.setState({marked: newstate });
```

Comment: Hello Ashok, this removes my old value from the state

Comment: You need to set state after the value gets change. Looked at my updated answer

Comment: `var s = Object.assign(obj , this.state.marked[0]);
  this.setState({ marked: s })` this clears my old values in marked state

Comment: Have you changed anything that is described in your question? Bcz based on your code, this might get work.

Comment: No, I haven't changed anything

Comment: Everything was ok with your code just remove, 0 index from `marked[0]` and it worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `...` spread operator inside `this.setState`:

```js
var obj =  {
        "2019-01-02":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-04":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2019-01-08":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-12-29":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        },
        "2018-11-27":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#fc3232"
        },
    }
    
        console.log(obj)
    
    var s = {...obj, 
        "2018-12-30":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
        }
    }
    
    console.log(s)
```

In React you can do this by:

```
this.setState({ marked: {...this.state.marked, "2018-12-30":{
            "disabled":true,"selected":true,"selectedColor":"#10cc74"
}})
```

Comment: Thanks @HarishSoni, can you tell me if How do I update this into state ? Something like `var s = { ...this.state.marked, obj}; this.setState({ marked: s});` Is this right ?

Comment: yeah that would work.
Let me know if your issue is resolved. Please mark it as answer if it does and give it a upvote to my effort

Comment: Thanks in ADAVANCE:

Comment: Did you got the result as desired?

Comment: No, I am still not getting the response I want

Comment: let me know the desired result you want

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: You are setting the state after spreading right. So it should do the Trick.
What you are getting then?

Comment: hello @HarishSoni can u explain to me this whats mean `obj={{...this.state.userLocation, ...this.state.region}}`?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in react. Keep your whole state and update the marked with new values using [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Just provide values to the handleMarked function to update the state. And delete dummy values for day and value.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    marked: {},
    tempMarkedDates: [],
  }
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

handleMarked = (day, value) => {

  /* Provide values to function params above and delete dummy values below */
  day = '2019-01-10';
  value = {
    disabled: true,
    selected: true,
    selectedColor: '#fc3232'
  }

  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    marked: {
      ...this.state.marked,
      [day]: value
    }
  },
    () => console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.marked))
  );
}
```